# Как изменить время сна цикла в зависимости от условия

Tags: python, циклы, while

Есть некий цикл while например:

```
while True:
    что-то там
time.sleep(5)
```

хотелось бы изменять значение time.sleep в зависимости от условия, например если бд пустая то time.sleep(3600) если нет то time.sleep(5) как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Открыть учебник по Python.
2. Изучить, что такое "переменная" и как ее использовать.
3. Изучить, что такое оператор if.

Потом попытаться написать скрипт примерно такого вида

```
while True:
    if условие1:
        a=5
    else:
        a=3600
    time.sleep(a)
```

Про то, как выйти из вашего бесконечного цикла -  оставляю для самостоятельной проработки.